# # Error: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level # On First Line of Code

Tags: python, indentation, maya

I'm getting an error in my python code when trying to import one of my scripts into Maya's memory.

Here's the code:

```
import solar_system as ss
import pymel.core as pm
import random
```

And I'm recieving this error:

```
# Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/maya/2012-x64/prefs/scripts\solar_system.py", line 66
#     '''
#          
# ^
# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level #
```

So, for some reason, it wants import solar_system as ss indented even? I don't really understand what it wants me to do.  Any help? Please?

Comment: Well, what's on line 66 of `solar_system.py`? That's where the actual error is. It says so right in the error message.

Comment: Huh. I guess it was just some comments I had at the very bottom of the file. I deleted them, and it's working fine now. Thank you, I'm very new to this, and don't understand the crypticness of the errors; so the translation of sorts was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file `solar_system.py`, there appears to be an indentation error on line 66. You might want to make sure that you're not mixing tabs and spaces for indentation. If you can post the first 70 lines of that file, we can tell you more about other possible errors.

Comment: Huh. I guess it was just some comments I had at the very bottom of the file.  I deleted them, and it's working fine now. Thank you, I'm very new to this, and don't understand the crypticness of the errors; so the translation of sorts was very helpful.